# Mouse click trigger action

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have some critical question: It seems a bit complicated, scenario as below.

I have my wordpress platform and inside a page i embedded an iFrame google map. And the map has some points , when user clicks, it will have a bubble popup in the map showing some details.

Now I need to make some changes so that when user clicks on the hyperlinks on the wordpress Page, it will trigger the bubble in the map,(Specific location) to popup and display the details. How can i achieve that?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
// Define your locations: HTML content for the info window, latitude, longitude
var locations = [['<div class="location"><a href="#" id="Singapore"><h4 style="margin-top:8px; margin-bottom: -8px !important; color:#334354">SINGAPORE (Head Office)</h4><p>168 Jalan Bukit Merah Surbana One,  <br/>    Singapore 150168. <br/><p style="margin-top:13px;">Tel : +65 6248 1288 <br/>Fax : +65 6273 9090<br/>Email : <a href="mailto:mails@surbana.com" target="_top">mails@surbana.com</p></p></a></div>',1.283261, 103.818849],
```

['Shanghai (Regional Office)

#801 ZhongRong HengRui Int’l Plaza, 
620 Zhang Yang Road, 
Pudong District, 
Shanghai 200122, China. 
Tel : +86 21 6881 0899
Fax : +86 21 6881 0800

',31.223363, 121.527130],

['Shenyang

#1503, Ouya Lianying Commercial Tower,
1A NanJing South Street, 
He Ping District, Shenyang PRC, 
110001, China. 
Tel : +86 24 2289 2258
Fax : +86 24 2289 2259

',41.777994, 123.403449],

['Yangon

Unit02-03 Union Business Centre, 
Nat Mauk Road, Bo Cho Quarter, 
Bahan Township, Yangon, 
Republic of Myanmar. 
Tel : +95 18603376

',16.801551, 96.161014], ];

// Setup the different icons and shadows
var iconURLPrefix = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/';

```
var icons = [
  iconURLPrefix + 'red-dot.png',
  // iconURLPrefix + 'green-dot.png',
  // iconURLPrefix + 'blue-dot.png',
  // iconURLPrefix + 'orange-dot.png',
  // iconURLPrefix + 'purple-dot.png',
  // iconURLPrefix + 'pink-dot.png',      
  // iconURLPrefix + 'yellow-dot.png'
]
var icons_length = icons.length;


var shadow = {
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(15,33),
  url: iconURLPrefix + 'msmarker.shadow.png'
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.92, 151.25),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  mapTypeControl: false,
  streetViewControl: false,
  panControl: false,
  zoomControlOptions: {
     position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
  }
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  maxWidth: 400
});

var marker;
var markers = new Array();

var iconCounter = 0;

// Add the markers and infowindows to the map
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    icon : icons[iconCounter],
    shadow: shadow
  });

  markers.push(marker);

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));


  iconCounter++;
  // We only have a limited number of possible icon colors, so we may have to restart the counter
  if(iconCounter >= icons_length){
    iconCounter = 0;
  }
}

function AutoCenter() {
  //  Create a new viewpoint bound
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  //  Go through each...
  $.each(markers, function (index, marker) {
    bounds.extend(marker.position);
  });
  //  Fit these bounds to the map
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
AutoCenter();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since these are different domains, you have to use web messaging (same as cross-document messaging).

For example in the sending window:

```
var o = document.getElementsByTagName('map')[0];
o.contentWindow.postMessage('location xyz', 'http://example.com/');
```

and in the iframe:

```
function receiver(event) {
    if (event.origin == 'http://example.net') {
          //consume location
    }
}
window.addEventListener('message', receiver, false);
```

Comment: Bro, thanks for your reply. The files are both in the same domain just different location. I am not looking how to post message rather make the mouse click response to be able to react on the iframe.